# Incorrect reshape of vtk->numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, vtk

I am reading VTK uniform grid into python. When I visualize a slice through the data in Paraview, I get the following (correct) image:

[image: VTK screenshot]

Then I visualize the slice using via numpy & pylab using the following script:

```
import vtk
from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy
import pylab

imr=vtk.vtkXMLImageDataReader()
imr.SetFileName('flow.vti')
imr.Update()
im=imr.GetOutput()

nx,ny,nz=im.GetDimensions()
orig=im.GetOrigin()
extent=im.GetExtent()
spacing=im.GetSpacing()

flowVtk=im.GetPointData().GetArray("|flow|")
flow=vtk_to_numpy(flowVtk).reshape(nx,ny,nz)
# bottom z-slice
flowZ0=flow[:,:,0]
# set extent so that axes units are physical
img=pylab.imshow(flowZ0,extent=[orig[0],orig[0]+extent[1]*spacing[0],orig[1],orig[1]+extent[3]*spacing[1]],cmap=pylab.gray())
img.set_clim(vmin=0,vmax=1000)
pylab.show()
```

[image: pylab output]

which seems to be out-of-phase. I tried reordering dimensions in `reshape(...)`, it did something, but it has never shown the data it is actually supposed to show.

Is there something obviously wrong?

**EDIT:** I also tried `reshape((nx,ny,nz),order="F")` (fortran ordering) and now I get a much better image (with jet colormap for better clarity) [image: reshape with fortran ordering] which is almost correct, but the data is suspiciously rotated by 90°, plus I would like some authoritative explanation which ordering to use and why (which one is used by VTK internally?).

**EDIT2:** to get the same view as in Paraview, I had to do `pylab.imshow(np.rot90(flowZ0))`; not sure why, so the question is still open:

[image: fortran and rotated by 90 deg]

Comment: What is the shape of `vtk_to_numpy(flowVtk)`? Shouldn't it return already the array with a correct shape?

Comment: @rth: `vtk_to_numpy` returns 1d array (that seems to be correct also as indicated by other examples at SO which always reshape afterwards).

Comment: Have you tried also to look at the data the spreadsheet view in paraview? And, just to be extra sure, you can also try GetArray('Flow') instead of GetArray(1)

Comment: @lib: thanks for the `GetArray("|flow|")` tip, it makes my script here easier. Spreadsheet does not show much, it is too much data to make sense of it. I added an edit on ordering, that might be the culprit.

Comment: flow=vtk_to_numpy(flowVtk).reshape(nz,ny,nx) I think the ordering of your array is z,y,x rather than x,y,z